# How to integrate a flutter app with 2 firebase database

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to have a dev and a live flutter app using the same repo on git bucket, which has different firebase database (a dev database and the live database). now my problem is, how do I switch through both of these firebase databases (use a different database when in dev mode and another for live) using the same flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using two separate Firebase projects, you can alternate between the two by using visual studio code.

Visual Studio Code provides that option as shown in the gif below:
[image: changing branches on VSC]

If you end up switching between branches, VSC will reload the project with the files included in that branch. Just make sure you have the [GitHub client](https://desktop.github.com) for verification concerns.